# Connect android app to server with socketio

Tags: android, sockets, server, socket.io, client

"I want to establish communication between a server written in Python and an Android app using Socket.IO. The server prints the IDs of each connected client to the console. However, when I try to connect with the Android app, nothing happens. How can I fix this?"

Here my server code:

```
import socketio
from aiohttp import web
#from ChargerUnit import occp_Request_Protocols

#ocpptest = occp_Request_Protocols("./config.json")
sio = socketio.AsyncServer(cors_allowed_origins='*')
app = web.Application()
sio.attach(app)

@sio.on('connect')
async def connect(sid, environ):
    print(f"Bağlantı sağlandı: {sid}")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    web.run_app(app, host='192.168.1.73', port=4011)
```

And my app code:

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import io.socket.client.IO;
import io.socket.client.Socket;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Socket mSocket;
    {
        try {
            mSocket = IO.socket("http://192.168.1.73:4011");
        } catch (URISyntaxException e) {}
    }
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mSocket.connect();


    }
```

I did the steps in this socketio blog and still not working